# Actionsheet enable scrollable

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiactionsheet

I have third party custom actionsheet (TSActionSheet) for dispalying names from database. It working fine. But the problem is if i have 5 names it displaying proper. If i add more than ten names i can't able to see the below names it hiding because of height. So, need to use scrollview for actionsheet.

```
TSActionSheet *actionSheet = [[TSActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Design"];

for (int i = 0; i<[categoryNames count]; i++ ) 
{
    NSLog(@"catearray is %@",categoryNames);
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:[categoryNames objectAtIndex:i] block:^{
    [self actionSheetClickedButtonAtIndex:i];
    }];
}
```

Comment: for more item to display use UITableview inplace of UIActionSheet

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make Scrollable Action Sheet then you have to add more content on Action Sheet. then Action Sheet automatically scroll. but you can not add functionality like this on ActionSheet. Apple doesen't support to edit his own control. if you want to still do it then make custom control for it.

Comment: Your answer discusses UIActionSheet, but the OP is using TSActionSheet.